# Querying RDF Properties Made by Jena with SPARQL

Tags: scala, sparql, rdf, jena

So, I've been playing around with Jena in Scala to try and get a feel for it, and I've come across a simple problem. Suppose you create a property with some code like `var myProperty = model.createProperty("myProperty")`, and then add it to your model with something like `model.createLiteralStatement(model.createResource(), myProperty, "test")` and you simply wish to retrieve this statement with a SPARQL query how would you go about it?

I have tried the following:

```
var sparqlQuery = "SELECT ?value " +
  "WHERE " +
  "{?subject " + "<myProperty>" +  " ?value." +
  "}"
val query = QueryFactory.create(sparqlQuery)
var queryExec: QueryExecution = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, model) 
val results = queryExec.execSelect
```

But sadly, the results are empty. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: seems you are missing a space after ?subject or is that a typo?

Comment: Do you use full URIs for the property? This is necessary.

Comment: And what is `store`? Please show a full, minimal and working example.

Comment: It was a typo. I was transcribing what I had actually wrote in a more generalized way. store was meant to be model. My bad! I'll update it now. The original query did have a space after ?subject as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the query, `<myProperty>` is a relative URI. The parser will expand this to a full (absolute) URI, probably adding the current directory as the base of resolution.

It will not match `createProperty("myProperty")`.

The data should have an absolute URI (e.g. `createProperty("http://example/myProperty")` and the query should agree `<http://example/myProperty>`.

You can use prefixes in the query.